# Laravel 5.2 won't persist manual login Auth::attempt

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm trying to authenticate a user from an email url. In my `Auth` model:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {

            if(isset($_GET['newuser'])) {

                $data = [
                    'email' => $_GET['newuser'], 
                    'token' => $_GET['token']
                ];

                return redirect()->action('UserActivateController@newUser', $data);


            }

            return redirect()->guest('login');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

This then forwards to a public view:

```
public function newUser()
{

    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $_GET['email'], 'password' => $_GET['token']])) {
        Session::save();
        return redirect('/');
    }

}
```

The `Auth::attempt` function passes, but when I then try to redirect the user the session is lost and they are forwarded back to the login view.

Edit: It should be noted that I'm using the built in auth and everything works fine outside of this modification.